# Undefined property: stdClass::$email CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, properties, undefined, stdclass

Hello I have Undefined property: stdClass::$email . Can you help me ?

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$email
>
> Filename: controllers/verifylogin.php
>
> Line Number: 48
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: D:\wamp\www\codeigniter\application\controllers\verifylogin.php
>   Line: 48 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: D:\wamp\www\codeigniter\index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

This is VerifyLogin Controller

```
class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user_model','',TRUE);
 }

 function index()
 {
   //This method will have the credentials validation
   $this->load->library('form_validation');

   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
   {
     //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
     $this->load->view('login');
   }
   else
   {
     //Go to private area
     // redirect('home', 'refresh');
   }

 }

 public function check_database($password)
 {
   //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
   $email = $this->input->post('email');

   //query the database
   $result = $this->user_model->login($email, $password);

   if($result)
   {
     $sess_array = array();
     foreach($result as $row)
     {
       $sess_array = array(
         'user_id' => $row->user_id,
         'email' => $row->email
       );
        // $session_data = $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$sess_array);
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);

     }
     return TRUE;
   }

   else
   {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid email or password');
     return false;
   }
 }
}
```

Home Controller

```
    <?php 

session_start(); //we need to call PHP's session object to access it through CI
class Home extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
 }

 function index()
 {
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
   {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data['email'] = $session_data['email'];
     $this->load->view('home', $data);
   }
   else
   {
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }
 }

 function logout()
 {
   $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
   session_destroy();
   redirect('home', 'refresh');
 }

}
```

User model

```
    <?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public function login($email, $password){

        $this->db->select('user_id','email','password');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('email',$email);
        $this->db->where('password',md5($password));
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() == 1){

            return $query->result();
        }
        else {

            return false;
        }
    }
    public function register($name, $surname, $email, $password)
    {
        $data = array(
          'name' => $name,
          'surname' => $surname,
          'email' => $email,
          'password' => md5($password)
            );

        if( ($name && $surname && $email && $password) != NULL){
          $query = $this->db->insert('users', $data);

        }
        else{
          return false;
        }


      }
     }
```

Login form

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Logowanie</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Widok Logowania</h1>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
    <br>
    <label for="password">Hasło: </label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj">
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: When i did var_dump($result)`array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[23]
      public 'user_id' => string '19' (length=2)` It looks like there's no email i don't know why

Comment: line 50 is `'email' => $row->email`

Answer (score 1):

I think there is problem in your form_open() method

```
<?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
```

You get your variable in controller `VerifyLogin` of function `check_database()`

So you form_open would be

```
<?php echo form_open('verifylogin/check_database'); ?>
```

and you forget to load

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

try to read manual [CI form helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Comment: ` Missing argument 1 for VerifyLogin::check_database()` I've loaded form in autoload: `$autoload['helper'] = array('form','url','security');`

Comment: remove $password variavle from check_database($password) here and check

Comment: and add $password = $this->input->post('password'); inside your check_database() function

Comment: still the same problem

Answer (score 1):

The Solution:
user_model.php

This

```
$query = $this->db->select('user_id','email','password')
```

Change to
`$query = $this->db->select('user_id,email','password')`

MY GOD!